# SqlDataReader issue

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqldatareader

The exception is :

> Invalid attempt when no data is present.

But I don't know why? Does anyone? ps: c=0 initially

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=E:\C #\InsertDeleteUpdate-Login\InsertDeleteUpdate-Login\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from info", connection))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if(reader.HasRows)
            {
                if (reader["Id"].ToString() == textBox1.Text && reader["Password"].ToString() == textBox2.Text)
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    MessageBox.Show("Hello!");
                    c=1;
                }
            }

            if (c==0)
               MessageBox.Show("wrong id or password");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to call reader.Read() before trying to access the data from the reader

Comment: ...where more precisely ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must call `reader.Read()` before you access any of the value members of it. The function will return a `bool` if the read was successful or not, the easiest solution is replace your `reader.HasRow` call with the read call.

```
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=E:\C #\InsertDeleteUpdate-Login\InsertDeleteUpdate-Login\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select * from info", connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if(reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader["Id"].ToString() == textBox1.Text && reader["Password"].ToString() == textBox2.Text)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Hello!");
                    c=1;
                }
            }
            if(c==0)
                MessageBox.Show("wrong id or password");
        }
    }
```

However, there are many other things you could do to improve your code, for example right now you query every row from `info` but you only check the first row returned. By using parameters you could put your check right inside the query itself.

```
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=E:\C #\InsertDeleteUpdate-Login\InsertDeleteUpdate-Login\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select 1 from info where Id = @Id and Password = @Password", connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if(reader.Read())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Hello!");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("wrong id or password");
            }
        }
    }
```

There are many other improvements you could do, for example you should not store passwords in the clear in the database and instead they should be hashed by a password hashing function, but I will leave that for you to look up on your own.

**UPDATE**: As Steve points out in the comments, a even better option is to drop the reader and use `ExecuteScalar()` instead. `ExecuteScalar()` returns the value first column of the first row or `null` if no rows where returned (If the value from the database was `NULL` it returns `DbNull.Value`). All you need to do is check the returned value is not equal to `null`.

```
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=E:\C #\InsertDeleteUpdate-Login\InsertDeleteUpdate-Login\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select 1 from info where Id = @Id and Password = @Password", connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;
        connection.Open();
        var result = command.ExecuteScalar();
        if(result != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("wrong id or password");
        }
    }
```

Comment: However I would use ExecuteScalar here.

Comment: @Steve Good idea, updated with example of its usage.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain thx a lot, i was not looking for help only for my problem but for any other way i can improve my code. You see , i m a begginer in databases, so any kind of help is welcomed. Thx again for your answer( both parts!) .                                                                       I would be thankful if you  posted another comment with a list of those many other things  i can change!

Answer (score 2):

First thing to say about your code is the fact that you should never store passwords in clear text in your database. The correct way to do it is using some kind of cryptography (There are numerous examples in this site about storing crypted password)

Now, your problem is caused by the fact that an `SqlDataReader` is initially not positioned over the first record. You need to request it to read the record before trying to get data. (And, at this point, is useless to call HasRows because the `Read` method will return false if there are no rows to read)

```
        ....
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if(reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader["Id"].ToString() == textBox1.Text && 
                    reader["Password"].ToString() == textBox2.Text)
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    MessageBox.Show("Hello!");
                    c=1;
                }
            }
            ....
```

Said that please look at the answer from [Scott Chamberlain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80274/scott-chamberlain) for a better approach to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

DataReader.Read returns a boolean indicating if there are more blocks of data to read, so if you have more than 1 result, you can do:

```
while (dr.Read()) {
  // read data for each record here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The SqlDataReader is a low level API that is quite error prone and makes your code verbose and hard to read.

If you can, I advice you to use something more high level. For example Dapper (https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) which is easier to use, easier to understand and nearly as efficient.

your code will be something like

```
User result = conn.Query<User>(@"
              SELECT * 
              FROM User
              WHERE Id = @Id
              AND Password = @Password", 
              new {  Id = id, Password = password }).FirstOrDefault();

if(User != null) {
    MessageBox.Show("Hello!");
}
else {
    MessageBox.Show("wrong id or password");
}
```